# Set ErrorCode on Exception

Tags: delphi

I need to include an error code on exception.

[Exceptions (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Exceptions_(Delphi))

```
type EInOutError = class(Exception)
       ErrorCode: Integer;
     end;
```

But I have no idea how to set the error code.
I tried:

```
type ECustomError= class(Exception)
       ErrorCode: Integer=129;
     end;
```

But no success, how can I set the error code?

Comment: Your code is attempting to assign a value in its definition. Surely this is not what you're looking for. You need to assign this at the time an exception is raised, correct? If so, then implement a constructor on this exception class, and when you create the exception, it will require that you pass this variable in.

Comment: do you want that errorcode to be shown or to be assigned to something else like a result of a function?

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout Only show.

Comment: could you add some code, because to show you need only to do 'raise Exception.Create('error code 129')'

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout Not necessarily. One of the beauties of the exception system is that you can implement your own properties and functionality in general on an exception class. Sure, you could do it that way. But suppose later down the chain, OP wishes to read that error code by itself? Do you expect it to be parsed out of the string?

Comment: @JerryDodge that is true but if your intentions are only to warn/report the user about error 129 than why bother to write a new class.

Comment: @JerryDodge I wrote my comment while you were editing yours, in that case then yes your answer is great.+1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) set this in the class' definition. There is no context here about where and why it's being called. Instead, you need to assign this in run-time, at any place where this exception may be raised.

This can be done by deriving your class from `EInOutError` and adding a custom constructor to it:

```
type 
  ECustomError = class(EInOutError)
  public
    constructor Create(AMsg: String; ACode: Integer); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor ECustomError.Create(AMsg: String; ACode: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(AMsg);
  ErrorCode := ACode;
end;
```

Then, when you raise the exception, you call it like so...

```
raise ECustomError.Create('Some error message', 129);
```

You could go a bit further and add this code to your message...

```
constructor ECustomError.Create(AMsg: String; ACode: Integer);
begin
  inherited CreateFmt('%s (Error Code %d)', [AMsg, ACode]);
  ErrorCode := ACode;
end;
```

Comment: The alternative is to not derive a custom class at all: `var E: EInOutError; begin E := EInOutError.Create('some error message'); E.ErrorCode := 129; raise E; end;`